# Apache: How to serve a Ruby project as a subdirectory of a PHP project?

Tags: php, ruby, apache

I have a Zend Framework PHP project that I am serving with Apache. I would like to slowly migrate this application to use Ruby on Rails. How can I configure Apache to be able to serve this Ruby application as a subdirectory of the domain that is hosting my PHP project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1. [Install Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_installing_upgrading_and_uninstalling_phusion_passenger)

Step 2. Add the following entries to `passenger.conf` (`/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`)

```
RailsBaseURI /rails_application
<Directory /path/to/the/rails_application/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

Step 3. Make a symlink in the virtual host’s document root called `rails_application` which  points to the `public` directory of the Rails application.

More information available in the [documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_rack_based_ruby_application_including_rails_gt_3).